# iTextAsian with iText 5.0.3

Tags: java, itext, cjk

iTextAsian came out on Year 2007 and the latest iText 5.0.3 comes out recently with modification of package name.

I tried to create a Chinese font set.

```
BaseFont bfCHS_MHei_Med = BaseFont.createFont("MHei-Medium", "UniCNS-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

When the .class is run, it said Exception = com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Font 'MHei-Medium' with 'UniCNS-UCS2-H' is not recognized.

I have modified the package name in iTextAsian to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.fonts. But there is no help too.

Anyone can give me some hints ?